# Wavesurfer 2.0 Events Implementation in React

Tags: reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I have been working on an audio player in React using Wavesurfer 2.0.  I can create the wavesurfer instance and use the methods, but can't seem to use the events.  In the code below i am checking for the playing audio file to finish and when it does, the console.log part works, but then the setState gives this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

```js
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.wavesurfer.on('finish', function () {
          console.log('Track Finished')
          this.setState({isPlaying : false})
        })
    }
```

Does anyone know the correct way to handle this? Does it have to do with trying to use this.setState inside of this.wavesurfer?

Comment: Use an arrow function for your callback and it will work

Comment: @PatrickHund Hadn't noticed that scoping detail difference before, glad I stumbled on this comment - I found this to be really helpful in understanding why https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, for reference this was the change:

```js
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.wavesurfer.on('finish',  () => {
            console.log('Track Finished')
            this.setState({isPlaying : false});
        })
    }
```